# Поиск в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть объект и нужно,чтобы в конце выводились только строки содержащие "link":

```
def traverse_object(obj):
    links = []
    # TODO тут надо реализовать нужный код
    return links


base_object = {
    "dsfwe": {
        "list": ["ewfew", 12],
        "link": "https://ya.ru",
        "object_story_spec": {
            "page_id": "641020669346927",
            "video_data": {
                "video_id": "366854860929577",
                "title": "10 лет решаем задачи родителей",
                "message": " Онлайн-школа «Фоксфорд»: +25 баллов к ЕГЭ, +100 к спокойствию родителей!\n⠀\n 10 лет решаем любые образовательные задачи: сдать ОГЭ и ЕГЭ, победить в олимпиаде, поступить в классный вуз, решить любую контрольную и исправить любую оценку!",
                "link_description": "Поможем достичь любой учебной цели!",
                "call_to_action": {
                    "type": "LEARN_MORE",
                    "value": {
                        "link_caption": "foxford.ru",
                        "link": "http://10.foxford.ru/students?utm_source = facebook & utm_medium = cpm & utm_campaign = fox10_reach_feed_parents & utm_content = sochi",
                        "link_format": "VIDEO_LPP"
                    }
                },
                "image_hash": "14e9e5cefa89889bf3443891aee85a12"
            },
            "link": ["https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/", 3]
        },
        "id": "6126978628477"
    }

}

extra_data = [
    "123",
    123,
    {
        "some_obj": base_object
    },
    {
        12: {
            "link": "http://netology.fx.ru",
            12: {
                "ob": {
                    "link": "http://n-group.ru"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

print(traverse_object(extra_data))
```

Comment: Поиск должен быть в extra_data или в base_object? Какой должен быть вывод для приведенного примера входных данных?

Comment: Поиск проводится по всему массиву.Вывод должен содержать строки со значением'link'

Comment: base_object в поиске участвует?

Comment: И еще раз, добавьте конкретный пример выходных данных. Из вопроса это не очевидно.

Comment: команда `python traverse.py`
должна напечатать вот это:
[
'https://ya.ru',
'http://10.foxford.ru/students?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpm&utm_campaign=fox10_reach_feed_parents&utm_content=sochi', 'http://netology.fx.ru',
'http://n-group.ru'
]

Comment: В `extra_data` нет `ya.ru`, значит данные должны браться и из `base_object`. Но почему тогда у вас в результат не попадает `"https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/"`?

Comment: Видимо по причине квадратных скобок или ошибка уже с другой стороны.Но вопрос в том как мне выполнить поиск по строкам со значением некоторым во всех этих двух словарях и уже провести вывод?Вот на этом и споткнулся